# ECS fargate UPDATE_ROLLBACK creating tasks with old task definition family

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I've an ARest service deployed on **AWS ECS fargate**. The current **ECS Task Definition** has a **Memory Hard limit** of 1 GB due to which I'm getting error

> JavaHeapSpace out of memory

resulting into failing cloudformation stack. I created a new revision manually on the AWS console with updated Memory Hard limit of 4 GB. But when I try "*Continue update rollback*", it's still creating the tasks with the older task definition resulting into continous provisioning and deprovisioining of tasks and the stack reaches `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED` state after timeout. This is also blocking any new pipeline deployment.

How can I switch to the new task definition permanently so that the service stack is successfully deployed and the pipeline deployments are unblocked?